# Import Statement to Pip Install Statement

Tags: python-2.7, pip, python-import

**Summary**

I'm looking for a way to find all of the required pip install statements, with version numbers, based upon the import statements used in a script.  I'll use the results to create a requirements.txt file for the environment configuration during deployment.

**Issues**

There is a deviation between the import name in python and the package name used by pip.  Also, when using sub modules, its not immediately apparent that a pip install of the parent would be required.  For instance, in our script we're doing:

```
import pandas as pd
#body of code
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(filename, engine='xlsxwriter')
```

So, if we just pip install pandas, we'll get an error that xlsxwriter needs to be installed as well.

**Attempts and Research**

***First Attempt***

```
#Import Packages
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import linear_model

#Create an Array of the Package names
imports = ['pandas','sklearn']

#find installed package version on local machine for each imported package
import pip #needed to use the pip functions
for i in pip.get_installed_distributions(local_only=True):
    for ii in imports:
        if str(i).find(str(ii)) != -1:
            print(str(i))

#pandas 0.18.1 is found but scikit-learn 0.17.1  is not
```

***Research***

The below from an SO post appears to list out all of the import names, but they after running the second answer in the post, the import names I would expect to see such as 'sklearn' were missing.

```
print(list(item[1] for item in pkgutil.iter_modules()))
```

Comment: I think you can try [pipreqs](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pipreqs).

Comment: @phd thank you for getting back; i'll test this and let you know what happens. Thanks again!